# Unusual bending moment at simply supported beam in etabs

Tags: moments, bending

The horizontal beam is simply supported. I have assigned pinned to released the moment at the both ends. However, there's moment spike near the end in ETABS, what's the problem ? I have checked thru the model and couldnt find any problem related to it .

The correct BMD shall be blue (sagging moment) all the way in the SS beam....

I have assigned the slab as thin shell

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have varying member stiffness everywhere. Can you upload the model with member end releases shown and a deflection diagram? Also, why the positive moment does not extend all the way to the left column? I guess the model contains errors.